# message property in fetch API's catch function

Tags: javascript, promise

Please allow me to ask a possibly easy question. Can someone tell me where the `message` property of argument `err` in catch function at the end of `fetch` API came from? For example in the code snippet below

```
fetch('exmaple.json')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => randomlyMadeFunction())
  .catch(err => console.log('Fetch problem: ' + err.message));
```

I know fetch returns a `Promise`, and at the end `catch` function takes *rejected reason* as parameter, in this case `err`. I search many articles on [MDN js reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference), but I couldn't figure out where the property `message` of `err` came from. Any explanation or hint would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: console.log(JSON.Stringify(err)). You can see all keys and it's value in console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an error occurs during `fetch`, either a `AbortError` or a `TypeError` will be passed to the `catch` callback, see [fetch Exceptions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch#Exceptions):

> - `AbortError` The request was aborted due to a call to the `AbortController` method `abort()` method.
> - `TypeError` The specified URL string includes user credentials. This information should instead be provided using an `Authorization`
>   header.

[`TypeError`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypeError) are `Error`s and therefore have a `message` property, see [`Error.prototype.message`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/message).